# Change private variable with a function without calling it in main

Tags: c++, oop, c++14

Can I change a private variable using a function without calling the function in main?

```
class F{
    private:
        int a, b, sum;
    public:
        friend void _sum(F& f);
// + setters, getters ...
    };
```

```
void _sum(F& f) {
    f.setSum(f.getA() + f.getB());
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to setup an invariant such that `sum` is always equal to `a + b`. If this is the case, then just get ride of `sum` and any `sum` setter all together and make any `sum` getter calculate the value directly each time it is called. If this isn't what you are trying to do, then I do not understand your question.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  If I had `F ob(4,2)` and call `ob.getSum()` the output is `0`, but if I first call `_sum(ob)` and then `ob.getSum()` the output is `6`. My question was if I could make `sum` get the value of `a+b`  without calling `_sum(ob)` in main.

Comment: Instead of storing `sum` as a member variable and returning it from `getSum`, implement the latter as `int getSum() { return a + b; }` Now, as if by magic, it always returns a correct sum.

Comment: You could update the `sum` variable every time you update `a` and `b`. I assume that you are using `setA()`, `setB()` to update `a` and `b`, inside the `setA()` and `setB()`, call `sum=a+b;`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.